# C++/Boost string replace: How do I replace '&' with '&amp;' only when & ends with a ;

Tags: c++, regex, string, boost, replace

I'm doing a replace for xml and I need to replace a `&` character with the `&amp;` only when the `&` character does end with a semi-colon.

Surely I can do this with replace_if, replace_all, or maybe the regex support in boost, but I any feeling dumb today...can't seem to find what I need.

Suggestions?

Comment: What about `&hello world;`?  You need more constraints.

Comment: Whitespace would allow the match in that case, has to be contiguous. This is for xml remember which doesn't allow & without using &amp;. I just don't want to replace a "&gt;" with "&amp;gt;"

Comment: Sounds much easier to replace-`em-all, and then write a regex to replace a few back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be that hard.  Use std::find to advance to the next &, then
scan ahead using find_if, find_first_of or boost::regex to find either
the ';', or something that would make you stop searching.  Something
like the following (untested) should work:

```
struct EndMatch
{
    bool operator()( char ch ) const
    {
        return isspace( static_cast<unsigned char>( ch ) ) || ch == ';' ;
    }
};

std::string
replaceAmp(std::string const& original)
{
    typedef std::string::const_iterator TextIter;
    std::string results;
    TextIter current = original.begin();
    TextIter end = original.end();
    TextIter next = std::find( current, end, '&' );
    while (next != end) {
        results.append( current, next );
        current = next;
        next = std::find_if( current, end, EndMatch() );
        if ( next == end || *next != ';' ) {
            results.append( "&amp;" );
        } else {
            results.append( '&' );
        }
        ++ current;  // Skip '&', processed above
        next = std::find( current, end, '&' );
    }
    results.append( current, next );
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the sed expression `s/&([^ ]*);/&amp;\1;/g` would do the replacement you are looking for. I'm not familiar with boost's string replacement, but the documentation says it supports sed style regular expresions.

Edit: after testing it in sed, the expression seems to need some more escaping. `s/\&\([^ ]*\);/\&amp;\1;/g` works for my test cases.

Edit 2: Slightly improved expression, and a breakdown:

`s#&\([^[:space:]]*\);#\&amp;\1;#g`

**Input pattern:**

`&` begins with literal character &

`\([^[:space:]]*\)` match and capture any number of non-whitespace characters

`;` ends with literal ;

**Output pattern:**

`\&` literal character & (needs to be escaped in the output pattern because & normally represents the entire matched string there)

`amp;` literal

`\1` print back the captured string of non-whitespace characters

`;` literal ;

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following regex with negative lookahead:

```
(&)(?!\S*;)
```

That matches a `&` only if it is not followed by non-whitespace character(s) followed by a  `;`.

[Perl script using above regex](http://www.ideone.com/502px)

I'm not sure if boost regex allows negative lookahead.

Comment: following by or ending with? My regex is rusty.

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace & with & amp;
2. Replace & amp;amp; with & amp;
3. Profit

(spaces inserted to prevent stackoverflow itself replacing them!)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use negative use look-ahead?

```
/\&(?![A-Za-z]+\;)/
```

This matches any & character which is not followed by a normal word plus the semi-colon.

However, not all systems support look-ahead's.  If yours don't, then you'll have to first replace all &'s, then convert the wrong ones back.  Without negative look-around's, regex's are not good at all in *not* matching something.